# How to fix this Error related to Modules in Python?

Tags: python, module, keyboard, syntax-error

Error message:

```
keyboard.py", line 6, in <module>
    keyboard.write("GEEKS FOR GEEKS\n")
AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'write'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have tried upgrading the  pip too and re installed the keyboard module too...

MY CODE is (source: [GEEKSFORGEEKS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/keyboard-module-in-python/))

```py
#Using Keyboard module in Python
import keyboard

# It writes the content to output
keyboard.write("GEEKS FOR GEEKS\n")


# It writes the keys r, k and end of line
keyboard.press_and_release('shift + r, shift + k, \n')
keyboard.press_and_release('R, K')

# it blocks until ctrl is pressed
keyboard.wait('Ctrl')
```

Comment: which is your os? I'm not sure in windows and mac but linux don't let you to use keyboard.write() unless you have administrator privilege

Answer (score 1):

If you've named the script you are executing keyboard.py it will conflict with the module that you are trying to import.
Try with simply changing the name of the script that you are trying to run.

Comment: Good job, you're pretty attentive.